# Значение umask для  755

Tags: shell, linux

Какое значение должно быть у umask для того, чтобы созданный файл имел права 755?

Answer (score 1):

022

Это число потом вычтется из 777, получится 755

Само собой, если у вас трехсимвольная нотация.

Comment: из 777 вычтется для папок... Мне нужен файл с правами 755

Comment: Папка как и мамка тоже файл.

Comment: Из ссылки выше: "As I said earlier, if the default settings are not changed, files are created with the access mode 666 and directories with 777."

Answer (score 0):

Читать тут: [What is Umask and How To Setup Default umask Under Linux?](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/understanding-linux-unix-umask-value-usage.html)

Comment: По другому: Сколько отнять от 666, чтобы получилось 755?

Comment: 777-755=22 на калькуляторе не судьба?